# Arch Installation

Tags: linux, arch-linux, system-installation

I have been thinking of migrating to Arch linux from Ubuntu but the only thing that is stopping me from migrating is the installation not the hardcore stuff but the internet connectivity.I am on a university wifi which requires us to sign into our accounts from the browser but on Arch installtion there won't be any browser to login into.I am posting a screen shot of the login screen that we get immediately after connecting to Wifi and opening the browser.

Any help is appreciated.[image: Just after opening the browser or after trying to access some website][image: After Login,now we can access the web]

Note:The wifi is open i.e. requires no authentication during the connection.

Comment: From the live medium you can use a text browser, like links, to connect to your network.

Comment: @jasonwryanTried links in Ubuntu terminal doesn't loads the login page,returns a blank screen with a redirect in upper right corner and ok in bottom left corner.

Comment: Go to the URL in a GUI browser and see what the redirect is, then enter that URL directly in your text browser...

Comment: Thank you,this the very same reply I have received from the Arch forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]As I was not getting the reply in right direction as users were arguing over Manjaro and Arch so I asked the same question in Arch forums and here is the link to that thread that solved my problem.Anyway thanks for your interest.Above is a screen shot from lynx.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1581394#p1581394

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cell phone, a usb tether is automatically recognized by dhcpcd and pretty handy when on the go.

Answer (score -2):

You could try a full install of something like [Manjaro](http://manjaro.github.io/about), which comes with a full desktop and all the usual apps associated with that. From there on, it's Arch as usual.

I have had to do this with Salix or Zenwalk, as an easy cheat to get installs of Slackware on some troublesome machines at work. Works like a charm.

Comment: @Klatu Thanks for the suggestion but what if I want to install only Arch not some fork? Gracefully I disagree with your answer,you are suggesting an alternative instead of a solution.

Comment: "From there on, it's Arch as usual" just suggests you know little about how Arch actually works. Manjaro and Arch are *not* the same at all...

Comment: I disagree. You can use all the usual Arch tools with Manjaro and treat it as a base install upon which to build whatever you want. If this alternative is not "pure" enough for you, that's fine, but if you are suggesting that Linux cannot be extended, then you need to learn more about Linux.

Comment: You can disagree, but that just compounds your ignorance. Manjaro uses different repositories, different packages, has different policies about releases (ie., doesn't "roll" with upstream) and the list goes on. It is like saying installing Ubuntu gives you Debian as usual...